# What does following output in CentOS 7 using yum mean?

Tags: centos, centreon

This is the problem Im facing after running command

```
yum update
```

```
...
Error: Package: centreon-installed-2.8.32-1.el7.centos.noarch (@centreon-stable-noarch)
           Requires: centreon-web = 2.8.32-1.el7.centos
           Removing: centreon-web-2.8.32-1.el7.centos.noarch (@centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 2.8.32-1.el7.centos
           Updated By: centreon-web-18.10.12-3.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.12-3.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.0-21.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.0-21.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.1-3.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.1-3.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.2-3.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.2-3.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.3-5.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.3-5.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.4-9.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.4-9.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.5-4.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.5-4.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.6-2.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.6-2.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.7-3.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.7-3.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.8-6.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.8-6.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.9-4.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.9-4.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.10-7.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.10-7.el7.centos
           Available: centreon-web-18.10.11-4.el7.centos.noarch (centreon-stable-noarch)
               centreon-web = 18.10.11-4.el7.centos
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can you please explain to me what is the actual problem the yum sees here? Im unable to decypher the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some 3rd party repository (`centreon-stable-noarch`) has wrong deps on some of its own packages.

It can also be related to a stale yom cache. Try issuing `yum clean all` *before* doing another `yum update`.